# Сделать раздел активным в аккордеоне

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать раздел услуги активным, чтобы при открытии страницы он уже был открытым

```js
  $('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Add the correct active class
    if($(this).closest('.accordion-item').hasClass('active')) {
        // Remove active classes
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        // Remove active classes
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('active');

        // Add the active class
        $(this).closest('.accordion-item').addClass('active');
    }

    // Show the content
    var $content = $(this).next();
    $content.slideToggle(500);
    $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).slideUp('fast');
  });
```

```css
.accordion{
  width: 100%;}

.accordion-item{
  position: relative;
  padding: 17px 0;}
.accordion-item .active .heading {
      color: #000;}
      
.accordion-item .heading{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;}
  .icon{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);}
    .icon:before{
      content: '';
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 0.2rem;
      background: #000;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 1px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
    .icon:after{
      content: '';
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 0.2rem;
      background: #000;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 1px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
      z-index: -1;}
.content{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;}
.content p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12%;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 16px;}
.content a {
  color: #222;
  display: block;}
.title {
  padding-left: 8.5%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">

           <div class="accordion-item">
               <a href="#" class="heading">
                   <div class="icon"></div>
                   <div class="title">Услуги</div>
               </a>
               <div class="content">
                   <p>
                   <a href="#r">Победная рассылка</a>
                   <a href="#r">Проверка контрагентов</a>
                   <a href="#r">Создание упаковки бизнеса</a>
                   <a href="#r">Компаниям - заказчикам</a>
                   <a href="#r">Соискателям</a>
                   <a href="#r">Финансовая помощь</a>
                   <a href="#r">Юридическое сопровождение</a>
                   <a href="#r">Лицензирование и сертификация</a>
             </p>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="accordion-item">
               <a href="#" class="heading">
                   <div class="icon"></div>
                   <div class="title">Тарифы</div>
               </a>
               <div class="content">
                   <p>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                  </p>
               </div>
           </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: Через добавление класса, как вариант.

Comment: пробовал, работает но криво, если переключаешь дальше зависает первый

Comment: сгенерировать клик на нужной вкладке https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/Event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  $('.accordion-item:first .heading').closest('.accordion-item').addClass('active');
     // Show the content
     var $defContent = $('.accordion-item:first .heading').next();
    $defContent.slideToggle(500);
 
 $('.accordion-item .heading').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Add the correct active class
    if($(this).closest('.accordion-item').hasClass('active')) {
        // Remove active classes
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('active');
    } else {
        // Remove active classes
        $('.accordion-item').removeClass('active');

        // Add the active class
        $(this).closest('.accordion-item').addClass('active');
    }

    // Show the content
    var $content = $(this).next();
    $content.slideToggle(500);
    $('.accordion-item .content').not($content).slideUp('fast');
  });
```

```css
.accordion{
  width: 100%;}

.accordion-item{
  position: relative;
  padding: 17px 0;}
.accordion-item .active .heading {
      color: #000;}
      
.accordion-item .heading{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 17px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;}
  .icon{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 3rem;
    height: 3rem;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);}
    .icon:before{
      content: '';
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 0.2rem;
      background: #000;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 1px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);}
    .icon:after{
      content: '';
      width: 1.5rem;
      height: 0.2rem;
      background: #000;
      position: absolute;
      border-radius: 1px;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(90deg);
      z-index: -1;}
.content{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 15px;}
.content p{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 12%;
  color: #222;
  font-size: 16px;}
.content a {
  color: #222;
  display: block;}
.title {
  padding-left: 8.5%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="accordion">

           <div class="accordion-item">
               <a href="#" class="heading">
                   <div class="icon"></div>
                   <div class="title">Услуги</div>
               </a>
               <div class="content">
                   <p>
                   <a href="#r">Победная рассылка</a>
                   <a href="#r">Проверка контрагентов</a>
                   <a href="#r">Создание упаковки бизнеса</a>
                   <a href="#r">Компаниям - заказчикам</a>
                   <a href="#r">Соискателям</a>
                   <a href="#r">Финансовая помощь</a>
                   <a href="#r">Юридическое сопровождение</a>
                   <a href="#r">Лицензирование и сертификация</a>
             </p>
               </div>
           </div>

           <div class="accordion-item">
               <a href="#" class="heading">
                   <div class="icon"></div>
                   <div class="title">Тарифы</div>
               </a>
               <div class="content">
                   <p>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                   <a href="#r">1</a>
                  </p>
               </div>
           </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: вот, то что надо, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1):

```js
let b = document.getElementById('b')
b.addEventListener('click',()=>{
console.log('qwa')})
var click = new MouseEvent('click', {
 'view': window,
 'bubbles': true,
 'cancelable': true
 });
b.dispatchEvent(click)
```

```html
<button id="b">батон</button>
```

[https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Создание_и_вызов_событий](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/Events/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B8_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B9)